# PHP Prepared Statements. $stmt, fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am updating a mysqli database query to use prepared statements. This is the current PHP code:

```
$randomQQuery = "SELECT question FROM question WHERE tagOne='".$sub."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$randomQ = mysqli_query($dbc,$randomQQuery);
$qRow = mysqli_fetch_array($randomQ);
$question = $qRow['question'];
```

This is my initial prepared statement attempt:

```
$randomQQuery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT question FROM question WHERE tagOne=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$randomQQuery->bind_param('s',$sub);
$randomQQuery->execute();
$qRow = $randomQQuery->fetch_array();
$question = $qRow['question'];
```

1. Do I need to name my variable $stmt? All examples i've looked at use that name.
2. If so, how do I distinguish between numerous SQL queries and the use of a second different $stmt?
3. Am i fetching the array and obtaining the $question correctly? I understand that 'bound results' are an option; are these best practice from a security perspective or just more efficient?

Comment: It is a variable, and you may therefore name it whatever you like.  `$stmt` is common just be cause it makes it clear that it contains a `mysqli_stmt` object as opposed to a `mysqli` resource.

Comment: To use `fetch_array()` as you are, you must call [`get_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php), but that isn't available on every platform.  [`bind_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) is, but is generally more tedious to use.

Comment: Much appreciated. The initial PHP code worked fine (aside from being exposed to SQL injection), can you see where my prepared statement version is wrong? Do fetch_array() and mysqli_fetch_array() have different availability? How would the get_result statement look?

Comment: Your prepared statement is all ok, but you need to call `$result = $randomQQuery->get_result();` and _then_ call `$qRow = $result->fetch_array()` to convert the prepared statement resource's result into a result resource.  Per the `get_result()` docs I linked earlier, you can only do that if you are using the mysqlnd driver, which not every system has. If you get errors about `get_result()` not existing, you'll have to use `bind_result()` instead -- the principle annoyance of mysqli vs PDO.

Comment: Thanks again. Didnt initially see the links in your comment!

Comment: The docs are confusing me a little. I am looking for a general method of getting query results into an array, with the bind_result() method, any ideas why the below doesnt work? Is the annoyance of mysqli v PDO just that they sometimes require different methods? Doesnt seem too much more tedious.

Comment: $resultQQ = $randomQQuery->bind_result($q);
$qRow = array('question'=>$q);
$question = $qRow['question'];

Comment: After `bind_result()` you need to call `$randomQQuery->fetch()`, then your bound variable `$q` will be populated and you can put it into the `$qRow` array as you have done (though that seems unnecessary - you can just use `$q` directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: No.

3: Fetching arrays is usually done by `while($qRow = $randomQQuery->fetch_array()) { }`. I'd go with `$row = $randomQQuery->fetch_row();`.

Comment: There's a `LIMIT 1` on the query, no loop is needed. Further, `fetch_array()` and its cousins don't necessarily always work with MySQLi prepared statements as they do with plain query result resources.  [`get_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) is needed to be able to use `fetch_array()` in that context in the first place.

Comment: I did mention 'usually done', right? Seeing as it is just one row by the use of `LIMIT 1`, `fetch_row()` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Not not really, in fact you didn't even named it $stmt?

2 - No need for this since #1 ;)

3 - It's ok... not great, all depends of your needs

What you're doing is only valid for 1 row, otherwise you need at least a while

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Best pratices would at least validate that execute didn't return false..

Also by default, it's using MYSQL_BOTH which gives you array and numbering array. You can save a bit of memory if you don't need both by using either one:

```
/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: 1+ for the tip about MYSQLI_NUM.  But where is $result coming from?

Comment: $result is the return of the $query() call. That was taken from the php page example directly:

`$result = $mysqli->query($query);`

Comment: @ROunofF if you use $mysqli->query($query) , will bind_param() be effective?

Answer (score -1):

This is some example code that is pretty simple to follow if it helps. I use $stmt (it's just the way I learned how to do it) and I've used this countless times. I understand it may not be exactly what you needed, but this works and may help or help anyone else having a similar issue.

```
include "../dbConnFile.php";

if($conn){

    if($_POST['example1']!='' && $_POST['example2']!=''){//checks input

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO database (example1, example2) VALUES (?,?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['example1'], $_POST['example2']);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    $result=$conn->query("SELECT example1, example2 FROM datasbase ORDER BY ____ DESC");

    if($result){
        while($tempRowHolder = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $records[] = $tempRowHolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <h3> Example Table </h3>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Example</th>
   <th>Example</th>
  </tr>
  
  <?php
   foreach<$records as $this_row){
    echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$this_row['example1'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$this_row['example2'].'<td>';
    echo '<tr>';
   }
  ?>
 </table>
 <hr/>
  <form action="filename.php" method="post">
   Example: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
   Example: <textarea cols="60" rows="5" name="comment"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>